# Blank Entries are getting saved in database (android)

Tags: android

I am trying to validate a form so that the blank entries do not get stored in the database. 
Code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.second);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addevent, container, false);
        // Edit Text
        ineventname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         mEdit = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText6);
         mEdit1= (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        ineventwebsite = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        incollegename = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        ingooglemap = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        inlocation = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        istartdate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        ienddate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText7);

        Button button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
         spinner = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
         category = new String[] { "Cultural", "Technical",
                    "Sports"};

         adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,category
                  );



            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            mEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // creating new product in background thread
                    f=1;f1=0;
                    new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                }
            });
            mEdit1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // creating new product in background thread
                    f1=1;f=0;
                    new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                }
            });

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
                    icategory=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();}

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

//              @Override
            }); 

        // button click event
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                //boolean r=validate();
               // Log.d("check",q);
                Log.d("check","Hello"+ineventname.getText().toString());
                if(ineventname.getText().toString()==""||ineventwebsite.getText().toString()==""||incollegename.getText().toString()==""||ingooglemap.getText().toString()==""||inlocation.getText().toString()==""||istartdate.getText().toString()==""||ienddate.getText().toString()==""){
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder1.setMessage("Please fill the fields");
                    builder1.setCancelable(false);
                    builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });             
                    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                    alert11.show();
                }
                else{
                    new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new details1());
                    ft.commit();
                }
            }
        });
return rootView;

    }
```

I have used `if(ineventname.getText().toString()==""` to validate the entry of the form. But still the blank values are getting stored in the db. How can this problem be solved??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because that is not how you validate a string. it should be

`if(ineventname.getText().toString().equals(""))`

Answer (score 1):

use 
`ineventname.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")`

instead of 
`ineventname.getText().toString()==""`